# Ideal gas Law best describes the properties of which of the following gases at 0 degrees Celsius and 1 atm?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

a. $\ce{PH3}$

b. $\ce{HBr}$

c. $\ce{SO2}$

d. $\ce{N2}$

I believe that it is $\ce{N2}$, but I'm not too sure, since technically all of them would act the same at STP.

Comment: They would act the same if they all were ideal, which they aren't.

Answer (score 4):

One of the defining characteristics of ideal gases is that ideal gas particles do not interact with each other, and there are no intermolecular forces between them. If a certain type of gas molecule has a molecular bipole, then each molecule will have ends with opposite partial charges. In a collection of gas particles, if the particles have a molecular dipole, these particles will attract and repel each other and thus will experience intermolecular forces. Because the two nitrogens in $\ce{N2}$ are equally electronegative, the bond and each $\ce{N2}$ gas particle will have minimal partial charges and thus minimal intermolecular forces. Thus, $\ce{N2}$ behaves very ideally.

Answer (score 1):

Ideal Gas Law disregards intermolecular interaction. So polar molecules will most likely differ from ideal gases to a higher degree than nonpolar molecules